Installing Singularity Error: make: *** .builddir: No such file or directory. Stop
I've been unsuccessfully attempting to install Singularity for a while now. I've updated to Noble, and tried to follow the instructions given on the Singularity CE Guide to install the latest version of SingularityCE (4.1.3), but when I run singularity --version or singularity-ce --version, my computer says I don't have Singularity. I also attempted to just have singularity do something for me, and it reiterated that Singularity hasn't been installed.
From what little I understand, the terminal seems to be unable to locate the build directory that was created during the compiling:
./mconfig && \
    make -C ./builddir && \
    sudo make -C ./builddir install

the last line that the code gave me before 'giving up' was make: *** .builddir: No such file or directory. Stop.
Am I right in thinking its something wrong with the build directory? How would I go about fixing this? Is it in the wrong place or something? Any help is appreciated.
